# Creating upper and lower bound slopes to a nonlinear equation statistically

Tags: excel, non-linear-regression, lower-bound, upperbound

So I'm working with some data and I've noticed that the best fitting trendline is a polynomial function rather than a linear equation. I've found a tutorial that's a couple years old that allowed me to at least generate the LINEST array for the regression and the TINV values for certain percentiles, I don't know how to plug them into the bounding formulas I found on this site, since they were for linear equations. So for an example, here is one of the arrays I've generated for it so far:

So I'm working with some data and I've noticed that the best fitting trendline is a polynomial function rather than a linear equation. I've found a tutorial that's a couple years old that allowed me to at least generate the LINEST array for the regression and the TINV values for certain percentiles, I don't know how to plug them into the bounding formulas I found on this site, since they were for linear equations. So for an example, here is one of the arrays I've generated for it so far:

```
-3.27055E-14 1.77069E-10 -3.43246E-7 0.00028586 -0.108005 58.81177

5.04074E-14  2.34805E-10 3.65532E-7 0.000217063 0.03924   1.122581

0.336886741  8.287261549 #N/A       #N/A        #N/A      #N/A

11.78648184  116         #N/A       #N/A        #N/A      #N/A

4047.401486  7966.729661 #N/A       #N/A        #N/A      #N/A
```

So I know that the second row are the standard errors of the coefficients, but how do I go about incorporating them into the formula? The formula I found allows for only one slope standard error and one intercept standard error, but I don't know how to go about adding in the others. Any and all help would be appreciated.

So I know that the second row are the standard errors of the coefficients, but how do I go about incorporating them into the formula? The formula I found allows for only one slope standard error and one intercept standard error, but I don't know how to go about adding in the others. Any and all help would be appreciated.